# Infinite scroll with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, infinite-scroll

I am trying to scrape the data from this [page](https://www.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiOTcyM2JkNTQtYzA5ZS00MWI4LWIxN2UtZjY1NjFhYmFjZDBjIiwidCI6ImQ1ZmE3M2I0LTE1MzgtNGRjZi1hZGIwLTA3NGEzNzg4MmRkNiJ9). The page has infinite scroll within an element in the DOM. I have the following `puppeteer` script to scroll all the way to the bottom to reveal all data so that I can scrape it. The first `page.evaluate` call is working as expected, scrolling to the bottom and revealing the further contents. However, subsequent calls are not working. I have tried using `await page.waitFor(2000);` to wait before I can scroll further but it does not seem to work. Kindly help someone!

```
// this script parses the data from http://covid.rcmedicrew.org/ using their /scripts/getSearch.php API
// install nodejs then npm install axios
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const siteURL = "https://www.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiOTcyM2JkNTQtYzA5ZS00MWI4LWIxN2UtZjY1NjFhYmFjZDBjIiwidCI6ImQ1ZmE3M2I0LTE1MzgtNGRjZi1hZGIwLTA3NGEzNzg4MmRkNiJ9";


async function callPowerBiApi(apiUrl) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs']});
  // const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
  await page.goto(apiUrl, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0});
  await page.waitForSelector('.innerContainer');

  await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll(".innerContainer")[1].querySelector(".bodyCells>div>div div:last-child").scrollIntoView());
  //await page.waitFor(2000);
  await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll(".innerContainer")[1].querySelector(".bodyCells>div>div div:last-child").scrollIntoView());
  await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll(".innerContainer")[1].querySelector(".bodyCells>div>div div:last-child").scrollIntoView());
  await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll(".innerContainer")[1].querySelector(".bodyCells>div>div div:last-child").scrollIntoView());
  await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll(".innerContainer")[1].querySelector(".bodyCells>div>div div:last-child").scrollIntoView());
  await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll(".innerContainer")[1].querySelector(".bodyCells>div>div div:last-child").scrollIntoView());
}()
```

Comment: was scrolling to the wrong element, fixed it `await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll(".innerContainer")[1].querySelector(".bodyCells>div div:last-of-type div:last-of-type div:last-of-type").scrollIntoView());`

Comment: Nice to hear--feel free to add a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I was scrolling to the wrong element, fixed it by using:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll(".innerContainer")[1]
    .querySelector(".bodyCells>div div:last-of-type div:last-of-type div:last-of-type")
    .scrollIntoView()
);
```

However, it seems that the previous results are getting cleared when you scroll down so will need another strategy to scrape it all.